# How to integrate iPhone with other non iPhone devices using serial port?

Tags: iphone, integration, serial-port

Anybody knows how to integrate iPhone with other non-iPhone devices using serial port?

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly. There may be some sort of serial line (i2c) on the dock connecter, but it is not exposed through the SDK, the `Made for iPhone`/`ExternalAccessory.framework` stuff is only for USB and BT.

You could conceivably use a WiFi/serial bridge (such things do exist) since you can send whatever you want over a TCP tunnel, but I doubt that is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Underlying `ExternalAccessoryFramework` for 30-pin connector it's the real UART handshaking (using Tx, Rx, Gnd, Vcc and some detect pins and no flow control) but not USB. Those pins of USB are only used for iTunes, Xcode and powering. The iOS app does not need to understand UART and only needs to send/receive bytes through `NSOutputStream` and `NSInputStream`.

But you need to pay Apple for [MFi(Made For iPhone) Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) first and buy some confidential IC to enable your accessory to communicate with iOS. They will require you to propose a product plan and expected sales and consider whether they would accept you as a MFi manufacturer.

Comment: That's the thing I can't get a handle on, whether I need to be in MFi for one-way iPhone -> device communication.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the info on using the ExternalAccessory framework from apple's developer portal.

You can't get the required serial handshake(?) info without joining the Made for iPhone program. This requires that you are developing a commercial device.

I have tried to get information on this protocol from apple through my university and have thus far failed.

Comment: The ExternalAccessory doesn't let you talk to arbitrary devices. In order to use it to talk to a serial device you would need to build a custom USB->serial adapter that implements the External Accessory USB protocol then encapsulate serial commands over it.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully received serial communication from the Arduino on the iPhone.  I made a google doc explaining my process.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Yi9_hcw8XSyYNCG2OJT9oHlTG-dC-Dnuc58VIULa81Q/edit