# Is it possible to make a (non jailbroken) iPhone emit i2c commands?

Tags: iphone, ios, hardware, i2c, interfacing

I want to control a [string of LEDs](http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/547149280/Infinite_extension_5050_RGB_LED_Flexible.html) directly from my iPhone. The [LED controller chips](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,74566.msg784589.html#msg784589) talk the [i2c](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) serial protocol.

Can I do this with Apple-supported APIs on a non-jailbroken iPhone? Which frameworks do I need to use?

Comment: How would you physically connect an i2c device to an iPhone ?

Comment: @PaulR USB-connector cable?! Alternative, A/D-changer connected to the headphone jack.

Comment: I was thinking by hacking a dock cable in some manner, or with some kind of USB b-socket-to-i2c adapter. Not headphone port, that sounds too flaky for what I want to do.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678789/how-to-integrate-iphone-with-other-non-iphone-devices-using-serial-port for a similar question.

Comment: I think the difference between my situation and that link is that I don't need to have the LEDs talk to the iPhone, I only need to send data _out_. But it was still handy, thanks.

Comment: This answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7274105/17294) implies I can just wire up a hacked dock cable and bit-bang away to my heart's content. Interesting...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you will need an external hardware to do that. iOS does not give you access directly to I2C in the docking connector.

[KissBos](http://kiss-box.com)  has a OEM board to do that, with a special firmware. You can connect to their board via WiFi, using a TCP based protocol, or via a RTP-MIDI based protocol (RTP-MIDI is implemented in iOS, you don't have to deal with the protocol details, it's just a MIDI port for your application).

If you want to go through the dock connector, you will need their USB interface (it will transform the USB into RTP-MIDI, which goes in the OEM board)

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that you can't do that. Apple is very strict about what you are allowed to and not. I spent days trying to find a way to get access to the iphone's bluetooth layer and ended up with my head against the wall (only a limited game api is public, else you have to go with the Made For Iphone program). However, you are able to do some stuff using the usb cable, but I guess that the possibilities are limited with that too.

Comment: Wait, you're saying I can't just use ExternalAccessory.framework to send arbitrary serial data to an arbitrary serial device? Did you do this investigation on iOS 5 or earlier?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678789/how-to-integrate-iphone-with-other-non-iphone-devices-using-serial-port